# Suppress gcc output to terminal when using only preprocessor

Tags: perl, gcc, c-preprocessor, newline, verilog

I am using the preprocessor of gcc to remove the comments from a verilog (.v) file (since the comment syntax is same as **C**/C++). I am using perl and hence used a shell command from my perl script

`gcc -E $dest > $commentsrem`

where `$dest`  is my verilog file renamed as a .c file. 
Since the preprocessor outputs data onto stdout, I redirected it to a file named `$commentsrem` . 
Now the problem I face is that I get messages on the terminal saying

> try.c:577: unterminated character constant

I guess this is because although in **C** you need to use '\' to continue a statement on a new line, verilog has no such requirement. That is what it is reporting.

Now although in spite of these, it achieves what I want, it's making the terminal messy. Any way to keep it quiet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting standard *error* to the null device would silence *all* error output from the preprocessor. Not generally recommended, as you will not see genuine errors either.

```
gcc -E $dest > $commentsrem 2> /dev/null
```

The better way would be to filter *known* messages from the stderr by use of `grep -v`, so you would still see *other* error messages. For this, you need to redirect stderr to stdout, because piping doesn't work on stderr:

```
gcc -E $dest 2>&1 > $commentsrem | grep -v "unterminated character constant"
```

The order of the redirections is important here. If you wrote `> $commentsrem 2>&1`, the error messages would end up in `$commentsrem` instead.

For details on the redirecting, ref. [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549737).

Comment: Thanks for this !! A little more help, suppose I want to suppress some other error strings too , say "Cannot find keyboard type" along with this error, what options do I use for grep.
-e doesnt work in my grep.

Comment: @gururaj: `grep -v "unterminated character constant\|Cannot find keyboard type"`

If you found my answer helpful, consider upvoting / accepting it. That's how this website works, you know?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Perl, the [vppreproc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?vppreproc) script can be used to remove Verilog comments.

```
vppreproc --nocomment in.v > out.v
```